# Oracle APEX cascading select lists in tabular form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have two column prod_line and prod_sku like seen in image..
[image]

Prod_line Column item is popUP LOV and Prod_sku Column Item is select.
i want to bind Prod_sku select list according to Prod_line selected value.and check prod_sku is select other row Prod_sku value are not same
anybody know please help .

Comment: If you're on APEX 5.1, you could use an Interactive Grid instead, which supports cascading lists natively.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, Apex doesn't offer that functionality "as is" - you'll have to write some code. Deneš Kubiček did that in his demo application, here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=31517:315:766265759280::::: (navigate to Section VIII, search for "**jQuery - Cascading LOV Tabular**").

There's quite a lot of code which I'm **NOT** going to copy/paste over here; it is free to use, but I'm not sure about copyright so - take that effort and visit Deneš's site for more information.